# Classification using ndarrays with mixed data types

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to apply the random forest classifier to a set of data that has mixed data types; notably it has both floats and strings. I realize that I could convert the strings by using something like one hot encoding, but my understanding is that one of the benefits of random forests is the ability to mix data types. So with that in mind, I loaded up my data into a structured array using loadtxt:

```
dtypes = np.dtype([
    ('height', np.float32), ...
])
X = np.loadtxt("dataset.csv", delimiter=",", dtype=dtypes, usecols=tuple(range(len(dtypes))))
```

But when I go to actually try running a classifier:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=1, n_jobs=-1, max_features='sqrt', n_estimators=200)
clf.fit(X, y1)
```

I run into this issue:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-3b0a3607bfd5> in <module>()
      9 clf = RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_split=1, n_jobs=-1, max_features='sqrt', n_estimators=200)
     10 print clf
---> 11 clf.fit(X, y2)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/forest.pyc in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    258 
    259         # Remap output
--> 260         n_samples, self.n_features_ = X.shape
    261 
    262         y = np.atleast_1d(y)
```

I realize that a structured array is different and has dimensions (in my case) of (11999,) so obviously it can't unpack the number of features. I know I could try reshaping the data, but my understanding is that ndarray needs to have a single homogeneous data type, which mine doesn't due to the mixture of strings and floats. How can I go about solving this issue?

Comment: Your dtypes should be floats, how can it understand or use strings? You'd have to extract some attribute from the strings such as length, tf-idf etc.. and use this as a feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` must be a matrix of floating-point values (`np.float32` for maximum performance with trees/forests). Anything else needs to be converted to floats by some form of feature extraction.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I didn't realize this. I used LabelEncoder and converted them to float32s and it worked just fine.

Comment: @RichardBender: please use `OneHotEncoder`. `LabelEncoder` is meant for class labels.